# Migrating from protoRPC (Python 2.7 to Python 3) Google App engine

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, google-app-engine, protorpc

We have an Google app Engine py2.7 standard. We use cloud endpoint framework to make web apis. We also use protorpc to make serialization and deserialize data.

For example

```
@cloud_endpointapi.api_class(resource_name="validateteacherpin")    
class ValidateTeacherPin(remote.Service):   

    MULTIPLY_METHOD_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(API_Validate_Teacher_Pin_Request)

    @endpoints.method(MULTIPLY_METHOD_RESOURCE, 
        API_Validate_Teacher_Pin_Response,      
        http_method='POST',
        name='teacher.validateteacherpinentered')



from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote


class API_Validate_Teacher_Pin_Request(messages.Message):
    field_1    = messages.StringField(1)
    field_2    = messages.StringField(2)
```

We are now migrating the application to Python 3.7 in Google App engine standard. protorpc is not supported in Python 3.7. How do we migrate the code?

Comment: Depending on how much time/resources you want to spend, maybe instead of moving to py3 in GAE, you could think about [migrating to Cloud Run](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-gae-python-migrate-4-rundocker) and using the [API Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run-grpc) instead of endpoints framework. Cloud Run will give you more flexibility for the future, and I just like more the Gateway than endpoints (and the [migration seems simple enough](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/endpoints-apis)).

Comment: Also, protorpc seems like it has not been updated for a while (according to the github repo). Maybe you should start using gRPC (this is the reason for Run+API Gateway, as it supports gRPC APIs). It is also an RPC protocol using protobufs: https://grpc.io

Comment: @jack-tileman, I'm considering similar migration, I'd really appreciate it if you can share your experience.